# Flutter is Route visible?

Tags: flutter

Is there any `visible` lifecycle in flutter navigator?

In the following navigation stack :

```
Home -> PageA -> PageB -> PageC
```

I want to listen on visibility at `PageB` that means I want to run a callback once I push to `PageB` or pop from `PageC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this package
https://pub.dev/packages/lifecycle

Wrap your root widget with LifecycleWrapper and onLifecyleEvent method to check for event

```
class _State extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LifecycleWrapper(
      onLifecycleEvent: (event) {
        if(event == LifecycleEvent.visible) {
            //DO whatever you want here
        }
        print(event);
      },
      child: Scaffold(),
    );
  }
}
```

These are all possible events

```
enum LifecycleEvent {
  push,
  visible,
  active,
  inactive,
  invisible,
  pop,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

create a constructor of C widget as

```
final VoidCallback yourCallBack; //this will be the function inside the B widget which call the setState which update the visibility of a widget.

C({this.yourCallBack});
```

Then call this yourCallback method inside `onWillPop` method as.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: (){ // its return type is Future<bool>
   //it will be called once C pop from backstack (back pressed);
   widget.yourCallBack();
    return true;
  },
  child: Scaffold(... your code ...)
 );
}
```

**Note:** If you call `Navigator.pop` to exit from C widget call `widget.yourCallBack();` it before.

Inside your B widget class  open the Widget C as

```
Navigator.of(context).push(FadeInPageRoute(
        CallRingingScreen(yourCallBack:yourMethod)
    ));
```

**Note:** Do not call it as `yourCallBack:yourMethod()`. call it without parenthesis.